# Android: subtotal of each item extracted from database

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a database for multiple entries of volume of water drunk in each day as follows:

```
1/1/2017 10:00 10ml
1/1/2017 11:00 20ml
1/1/2017 14:00 50ml
2/1/2017 08:00 20ml
2/1/2017 10:00 30ml
3/1/2017 19:00 80ml
```

### Question:

In order to they are as x-axis and y-axis for plotting chart, it would be great for having subtotal for each different date.

How could it by coded such that I can get a list of pair value by date (x axis) and the subtotal of that date (y axis)? The result should be as follows:

```
1/1/2017, 80ml
2/1/2017, 50ml
3/1/2017, 80ml
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with-  querying the database?  Turning the results into a list?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know the way to retrieve data from database into a arraylist.  But i dont know the overall way to make subtotals.  Should I retrieve the date and volume into two arraylist and then loop over date array and add amount in the volume array?  Would there be faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used my way at last: Simply sort the date of the arraylist first, and then loop through the arraylist and use a variable to store the subtotal the date, i.e. when the date is same as the date of the record before, add to the subtotal, if the date is different,  save the subtotal of the previous date and reset the subtotal.